# How to store NSTimeInterval values into a NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, nsmutablearray, nstimeinterval

I have a requirement where i have a Video that is played using `MPMediaPlayerController`. Along with the video i have two buttons where i need to capture the current playback time when the button are clicked and store all the relevant clicks individually. I am able to get the current playback time of the video using "currentPlaybackTime" property which returns `NSTimeInterval`. But can someone help me in how to store all the `NSTimeInterval` values into an `NSMutableDictionary`. I have tried the following ways:

```
-(void)onClickOfGood {
    NSLog(@"The current playback time in good:%g",moviePlayerController.currentPlaybackTime);
    currentPlaybackTime = moviePlayerController.currentPlaybackTime;
    //NSArray *arrayContainsGoodClicks = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:currentPlaybackTime, nil ];
    NSNumber *goodTimeIntervals = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:currentPlaybackTime];
    NSMutableArray *arrayContainsGoodClicks = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:goodTimeIntervals,nil ];
    NSLog(@"The total count of Array is: %i",[arrayContainsGoodClicks count]);}
```

But everytime after the click of good button i am getting the Array count as only 1. Can someone please throw a light on where i am going wrong?

Comment: Are you creating a new array every time a button is tapped?

Comment: I have rectified the mistake..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But everytime after the click of good button i am getting the Array count as only 1.

This is not surprising, considering that you are creating a brand-new `NSMutableArray` on the previous line.

To fix this, you need to make `NSMutableArray *arrayContainsGoodClicks` an *instance variable* (AKA ivar), initialize it to `[NSMutableArray array]` in your designated initializer, and then use

```
[arrayContainsGoodClicks addObject:goodTimeIntervals];
```

to add objects to the array.

If you are looking to use `NSMutableDictionary` instead, the strategy would be identical, except you would need to decide on an object that you would like to use as unique keys to your `NSDictionary`. Also remember that `NSMutableDictionary` is not ordered, so you might need to take care of sorting each time you display your dictionary items to users.

Comment: Thanks a lot..Somehow i tried out myself and surprisingly it was the same suggested. Feels great that i was on the right track..[arrayContainsGoodClicks addObject:goodTimeIntervals];
    NSLog(@"The total count of Array is: %i",[arrayContainsGoodClicks count]); this thing did the trick..

Answer (score 1):

You need to create `arrayContainsGoodClicks` only once (in init method for example) and then add value to this array in your button handler:

```
//.h
NSMutableArray *arrayContainsGoodClicks;

//.m - init
arrayContainsGoodClicks = [NSMutableArray array];

//.m - button handler
[arrayContainsGoodClicks addObject:goodTimeIntervals];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your array and store it as a ivar.

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *clicksArray;
...
@synthesize clicksArray;
```

Now in your -init method create the array like..

```
self.clicksArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

And add the object to the array each time so your -onClickOfGood would become something like...

```
...
[self.clicksArray addObject: goodTimeIntervals];
NSLog(@"The total count of Array is: %i",[self.clicksArray count]);
```